# Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber' after installing cucumber-electron globally

Tags: npm, cucumber, electron

I need to use cucumber to implement BDD in a project. My team is using electron, so I've decided to use cucumber-electron in order to run some tests. I've obviously installed cucumber and cucumber-electron, and in some other threads, the common suggestion was to install cucumber globally, I have also done this.

I've added the dependency on the package.json file, however, when I try to run a test with the command ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-electron ./features/my_feature.feature:123 -i, I get the error that the module couldn't be found.